# Why GET request runs twice in Flask app Python?

Tags: python, flask, get, request, localhost

my code is the following:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify

persistant = 0
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/counter')
def counter():
    global persistant 
    persistant += 1
    return str(persistant)

if  __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host = '0.0.0.0', port = 5000)
```

When I visit 127.0.0.1:5000 I first get '1' and when I refresh I get '3' and then '5' and so on. Why is this happening ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with Flask, but from looking at the code does that not make sense? You're incrementing the variable each time, right?

Comment: Are you visiting 127.0.0.1:5000 with a web browser?

Answer (score 1):

Your host in 0.0.0.0, and you are visiting 127.0.0.1. Perhaps, another app is running at 127.0.0.1? Moreover, according to the code, you need to visit `0.0.0.0:5000/counter` to observe the results of the code above.